# pickup "unique item" of a field in a django model using python

Tags: python, django, r, unique

I am learning to use django and python now and I have a little task as below:

I regular keep record of my monthly investment data, and create a django model as below:

```
class money_tx(models.Model):
    tx_date = models.DateField()
    investment_plan = models.ForeignKey(investment_plan)
    tx_type_choice = (
        ("deposit","deposit"),
        ("withdrawal","withdrawal"),
    )
    tx_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=tx_type_choice)
    tx_amt = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16,decimal_places=6)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-tx_date"]
```

I am trying to create a view in django which will tell me which fund purchase information for a particular month is not yet entered, the output should be something like this:

```
DATE    PLAN_A  PLAN_B  PLAN_C
2010-01 PRESENT MISSING PRESENT
2010-02 PRESENT MISSING PRESENT
2010-03 PRESENT MISSING MISSING
```

Being a regular user of R, I am thinking of the above output as a `dataframe`, so I need to create a dataset something like the one below before I can have my output:

```
INV_PLAN  DATE    STATUS
PLAN_A    2010-01 PRESENT
PLAN_A    2010-02 PRESENT
PLAN_A    2010-03 PRESENT
PLAN_B    2010-01 MISSING
PLAN_B    2010-02 MISSING
PLAN_B    2010-03 MISSING
PLAN_C    2010-01 PRESENT
PLAN_C    2010-02 PRESENT
PLAN_C    2010-03 MISSING
```

I am planning to create a dictionary object (something like `temp = {'test':[1,2,3],'temp':['a','b','c']}`), and use `for loop` to generate the status.

I am create the `date` field in the dictionary object without problem, but how can I extract the unique `PLAN_NAME` from my model?

I don't know if my way of "thinking from R perspective" is OK when I am trying to write python script. Please comment, or should I do it using MySQL way?. And sorry for the anti-pythonic naming of my objects. Thanks.

#### Update 01

Thanks for DrTyrsa's answer, it is almost ok, here's an additional piece of information:

```
class investment_organization(models.Model):
    organization_abbre = models.CharField(max_length=20)    
    organization_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.organization_abbre

class investment_plan(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(investment_organization)
    plan_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["organization", "plan_code"]

    def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s - %s' % (self.organization, self.plan_code)
```

My investment plan comprise of two pieces of information, one of them is the company name, which is stored in another model, how can I include it in my final output like below:

```
ORG    INV_PLAN  DATE    STATUS
ORG_A  PLAN_A    2010-01 PRESENT
ORG_A  PLAN_A    2010-02 PRESENT
ORG_A  PLAN_A    2010-03 PRESENT
ORG_A  PLAN_B    2010-01 MISSING
ORG_A  PLAN_B    2010-02 MISSING
ORG_A  PLAN_B    2010-03 MISSING
ORG_B  PLAN_C    2010-01 PRESENT
ORG_B  PLAN_C    2010-02 PRESENT
ORG_B  PLAN_C    2010-03 MISSING
```

Thanks again.

Comment: What is `FUND_NAME`? How do you get it?

Comment: @DrTyrsa: I fixed the `FUND_NAME` issue, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your dataset:

```
from itertools import groupby

money = money_tx.objects.order_by('-tx_date')
plans = investment_plan.objects.select_related()
result = []

for date, group in groupby(money, lambda x: x.tx_date):
    plans_for_date = set(x.investment_plan_id for x in group)
    for plan in plans:
        data = {'ORG': plan.organization.organization_name,
                'INV_PLAN': plan.plan_code,
                'DATE': date,
                'PRESENT': (plan.id in plans_for_date)}
        result.append(data)

print result
```